# Linux deleted files with spaces

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I have files whose name has spaces in linux and want to delete (or rename) from the command line. I've looked at several sites and say that we should put \ before the space, put '', put " " ... but none works for me. It is as if split in two by name where space. What I can do? Is it something in my settings linux console? They also say that there are many files folder, and are not mine, that is, I just want to do it for my family, not for every wallet. I put an example of what you say: ((((No existe fichero o directorio means not exists file or directory))))

```
 ->ls -lrt SINCERHOG\ 150626*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s10283 dessiis  167 jun 26 09:25 SINCERHOG 150626092551.xls
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s10283 dessiis    0 jun 26 09:35 SINCERHOG 150626093540.xls
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s10283 dessiis 2306 jun 26 09:59 SINCERHOG 150626095953.xls
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s10283 dessiis 2306 jun 26 10:12 SINCERHOG 150626101237.xls


 ->rm SINCERHOG\ *
 ls: no se puede acceder a SINCERHOG: No existe el fichero o el directorio
 ls: no se puede acceder a 150626092551.xls: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a SINCERHOG: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a 150626093540.xls: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a SINCERHOG: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a 150626095953.xls: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a SINCERHOG: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a 150626101237.xls: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Comment: Possible duplicate on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/439413/delete-multiple-files-on-linux-with-spaces-in-file-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your shell, when you invoke `rm SINCER*` the star (`*`) in `SINCER*` makes your shell think `SINCER*` is a pattern and thus file name expansion kicks in. Thus replacing the pattern with the (space separated) list of filenames resulting in the command

```
rm SINCERHOG 150626092551.xls SINCERHOG 150626093540.xls
```

But what you want is

```
rm "SINCERHOG 150626092551.xls" "SINCERHOG 150626093540.xls"
```

You could also try

```
rm SINCERHOG\ *
```

Comment: It does not work. In doing so it is as if the name divided into two where space is, and transform it into two files whose names would be every word of the name. Look for more information editing @Denis

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: How do I know that? @Denis

Comment: /bin/ksh

                  @Denis

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your example clearly. But if there are spaces in file name put the file name in double quotes as shown below while passing to the command

If your file name is as follows

```
> ls *
  my file name.txt
> rm "my file name.txt"
```